# How to Convert windows phone 8.1 runtime to silverlight 8.1

Tags: silverlight, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-rt, artoolkit

I want to add AR toolkit GART in my windows phone 8.1 app which is under completion, the app is almost completed in windows ph 8.1 Runtime. Now when i was trying to add GART in that I came to know that it is not possible in windows phone 8.1 apps, rather it is possible in silverlight. I want to ask if there is any possibility that we can convert our windows phone 8.1 app to silverlight or any other VR tool which will work in win 8.1 runtime??? I only have to display few pointers of latitudes and longitudes on GART.

Answer (score 1):

don't know if it's too late, but if not, you should take a look at a book by Ricky Brunditt (http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/my-book/), it has code to build an augmented reality App for Win8, but it can easily be done for Windows Phone 8.1 RT